# Vagrant + PHPUnit performance on PC too slow compared to Mac

Tags: vagrant

I recently added a pretty big PHPUnit test suite to a LAMP application in a vagrant box on PC.

The test suite involves setting up/tearing down the seed database before every test from an XML seed, as per PHPUnit's documentation. [see PHPUnit database testing.](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/database.html)

I noticed that the same test suite runs more than 10 times faster using the same vagrant box but on Mac. Same with CI (CircleCI), the suite runs amazingly fast there.

I did some investigation and it seems that the slow part is - unsurprisingly - the `getDataSet` step which loads the fixtures.

The suite takes about 2 minutes to run on PC, and less than 20 seconds on Mac. That is surprising to me.

Anybody knows why there's such a drastic difference in performance between Mac and PC running the same Vagrant box and test suite?

Thank you

Comment: What is your mac vs pc hardware configuration?

Comment: Macbook 16bg of DDR3 ram, 2.5 GHz i7 and a 500gb HDD. PC is a Dell XPS13 with an i5 processor and 8gb of DDR3 ram and a 250gb SSH.